# Save a file from Enterprise Architect Script

Tags: csv, jscript, enterprise-architect

I'm tring to create a script thats shows a dialog where I can select a path to save a file. The following got it almost, but this is to open a file, not save it.

```
var filePath = OpenCSVFileDialog();
var fileName = GetFilenameFromPath(filePath);    


function OpenCSVFileDialog()
{
    var Project;
    var Filename, FilterString, Filterindex, Flags, InitialDirectory, OpenorSave, filepath;

    Filename = "";
    FilterString = "CSV Files (*.csv)|*.csv|All Files (*.*)|*.*||";
    Filterindex = 1;
    Flags = 0;
    InitialDirectory = "";
    OpenorSave = 0;

    Project = Repository.GetProjectInterface();
    filepath = Project.GetFileNameDialog(Filename, FilterString, Filterindex, 
                                         Flags, InitialDirectory, OpenorSave);

    return filepath;
}

function GetFilenameFromPath(filePath)
{
    var bsindex, fileName;

    // find the last backspace in the file path
    bsindex = filePath.lastIndexOf("\\");

    if (bsindex > 0)
    {
        // get the name of the file only - minus the directory path
            fileName = filePath.substring(bsindex+1, filePath.length);
    }
    else
    {
        fileName = filePath;
    }

    return fileName;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GetFileNameDialog` is a new function in V13. Try different parameters for the `OpenOrSave` parameters (the docu might be flawed as well). Sparx always ships banana software! If it doesn't work either, send a bug report.

Alternatively (preferred!) use the operation pointed out by @Hue.

Comment: Never actually used GetFileNameDialog, good thing I did'nt if its broken

Comment: Thanks thomas and Hue, i just used OpenOrSave = 1;

Comment: Since I won't, please send a bug report so the docu will be updated. Thanks.

Comment: if GetFileNameDialog worked with OpenOrSave=1 worked, then there is no bug

Answer (score 3):

To get the file path, use the `Jscript-Dialog` script available in the EAScriptLib Script group, it will prevent you from rewriting the whole code for getting the dialog.

(To reference another script, use `!INC`, in this case, put `!INC EAScriptLib.JScript-Dialog` to the top of your script)

Call `DLGSaveFile(filterString,filterIndex)` and provide:

- the filter string, in your case its `CSV Files (*.csv)|*.csv|All
  Files (*.*)|*.*||`
- The index of the filter(in the previous point) you want to use, which you are already providing

It will return the path of the file.

You can use `Project.GetFileNameDialog`, it's the same thing but with more parameters [also, here's a link](http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/13.0/automation/project_2.html)

If you use the CSV library to create your CSV file, then your file should be exported once you call the `CSVEExportFinalize()` function. You must have called `CSVEExportInitialize(filepath,columns,exportcolumsHeadings)` first

For any file, it can be done with JScript and VBScript, **but not javascript**

JScript

```
var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
var a = fso.CreateTextFile("c:\\testfile.txt", true);
a.WriteLine("This is a test.");
a.Close();
```

VB

```
Dim fso, MyFile
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set MyFile = fso.CreateTextFile("c:\testfile.txt", True)
MyFile.WriteLine("This is a test.")
MyFile.Close
```

[Microsoft Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9ty6h50(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: He's focusing on the call that asks for the filename!

Comment: @ThomasKilian eh didnt pay too much attention to his code, thought he was trying to save the file, not getting the actual path... will edit my answer

Comment: Iit is possible to do this in JavaScript - use var fso = new COMObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");